# Django admin raw_id_fields - 404 on admin/js/related-widget-wrapper.js

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-admin

I'm trying to use the admin `raw_id_fields` in my application and it works locally, but in production I get a 404 on admin/js/related-widget-wrapper.js.

I checked the folder (static/admin/js) and the file is there but, for some reason, I can't access it (when I try directly with the URL on browser, it shows the 404 error page).

Due to this error, it's not showing the search icon.

The django version is 1.8.2 and I use Nginx, gunicorn and HTTPS in production server.

Comment: Which folder did you check? Is it the one pointed by nginx? Is it served over HTTPS as well? Have you run `collectstatic` since you upgraded to django 1.8?

Comment: Which folder did you check? [static/admin/js] Is it the one pointed by nginx? [yes, and it's normal for the other files] Is it served over HTTPS as well? [yes] Have you run collectstatic since you upgraded to django 1.8? [yes]

Comment: Did you compare permissions and ownership of the file with another file? As well as permissions of the parent directories. It may be helpful to have full absolute paths and the related part of your nginx conf file.

Comment: I haven't compared permissions and ownership.. I don't have SSH access to the server in my current computer, but i'll do this tonight and send the complete answer.  
The problem is the same that the one described here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24655
But didn't work for me..